# How can I use sed or awk to delete lines matching certain field criteria?

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I have following kind of data :

```
 1  abc    xyz   -    -    2   mno
 2  lnm    dse   -    -    3   pqr
 3  ebe    aaa   xhd  asw  4   pow
 4  abc    fww   wrw  ffp  3   ffw
```

I would like to **delete** the lines which satisfies the following two conditions:

1. 4th & 5th column are blank
2. The row number of the corresponding line is not contained in the 6th column of any other line

In this case line 1 should be deleted. How could I do it in sed/awk or most suitable scripting language for this case.

Comment: The title of the question is asking something orthogonal to the question body.

Comment: According to your two criteria, the first two lines in your example should be deleted because neither have the first and six columns equal.

Comment: the relation between first and second requirement is 'and' not 'or'.

Comment: According to your updated example, why isn't line 2 also being deleted? Both the 4th and 5th fields are "blank" and its "index value" of 2 if not contained in the 6th column (3)

Comment: line 2 is not deleted, its because its index *2* is contained in the 6th column of first row.

Comment: So your criteria is really "The index value of the corresponding line is not contained in the 6th column **of any other line**" ?

Comment: If there are values in the  4th and 5th value, i should not bother about whether the index value is contained or not.If there are no values in the 5th and 6th column, i have to check if its index is contained in any of the rows or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `perl`:

Content of **script.pl**:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Accept one argument, the input file.
@ARGV == 1 or die qq[Usage: perl $0 input-file\n];

my ($lines, %hash);

## Process file.
while ( <> ) {
        ## Remove leading and trailing spaces for each line.
        s/^\s*//;
        s/\s*$//;

        ## Get both indexes.
        my ($idx1, $idx2) = (split)[0,5];

        ## Save line and index1.
        push @{$lines}, [$_, $idx1];

        ## Save index2.
        $hash{ $idx2 } = 1;
}

## Process file for second time.
for ( @{$lines} ) {

        ## Get fields of the line.
        my @f = split /\s+/, $_->[0];

        ## If fourth and fifth fields are empty (-) and first index exists as second 
        ## index, go to next line without printing.
        if ( $f[3] eq qq[-] && $f[4] eq qq[-] && ! exists $hash{ $_->[1] } ) {
                next;
        }

        ## Print line.
        printf qq[%s\n], $_->[0];
}
```

Run the script (**infile** has the data to process):

```
perl script.pl infile
```

And results:

```
2  lnm    dse   -    -    3   pqr
3  ebe    aaa   xhd  asw  4   pow
4  abc    fww   wrw  ffp  3   ffw
```

Answer (score 3):

May be something like this could work -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$6];next} 
($4 ~ /[- ]/ && $5 ~ /[- ]/) && !($1 in a){next}1' file file
```

#### Condition:

> If `Column 4 and Column 5 are blank` **AND** `Index not present in Column 6`, we skip that line and we print everything else.

#### Explanation:

> We use `NR` and `FNR` built-in variables and pass the same file twice. In the first run, we scan thru the file and store `Column 6` in an array. `next` is used to prevent the second `pattern{action}` statement from running until the first file is being read. Once, the file is completely read, we test the same file against your condition. If the Column 4 and Column 5 are blank, we look at the index and if it is not in the array then we skip the line using `next`, else we print it.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
 1  abc    xyz   -    -    2   mno
 2  lnm    dse   -    -    3   pqr
 3  ebe    aaa   xhd  asw  4   pow
 4  abc    fww   wrw  ffp  3   ffw

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==FNR{a[$6];next} ($4 ~ /[- ]/ && $5 ~ /[- ]/) && !($1 in a){next}1' file file
 2  lnm    dse   -    -    3   pqr
 3  ebe    aaa   xhd  asw  4   pow
 4  abc    fww   wrw  ffp  3   ffw
```

Comment: Actually, there is a logical error. The 2nd condition should be a logical OR since you negated the match `($4 !~ /[- ]/ || $5 !~ /[- ]/)`

Comment: True, I corrected it. Also, I realized there was no need for indexing the array. Simple `a[$6]++` would suffice. Thanks! :)

Comment: I read OP's last comment. Have modified the second part of `awk`.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to increment it, just `a[$6]` will suffice. I was half way redoing my answer after I realized I needed to look at file twice but I was using END{} and it was getting too long and I knew there had to be a better way.  Passing the same file twice and using `NR==FNR` is definitely the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -rn 's/^.*(\S+)\s+\S+$/\1/;H;${x;s/^|\n/:/gp}' file | 
sed -r '1{h;d};/^(\s*\S*){3}\s*-\s*-/{G;/^\s*(\S*).*:\1:/!d;s/\n.*//}' - file
 2  lnm    dse   -    -    3   pqr
 3  ebe    aaa   xhd  asw  4   pow
 4  abc    fww   wrw  ffp  3   ffw
```

Explanation:

1. Read the file and build a look-up table from column 6 delimited by `:`
2. Read the table (first line) into the hold space (HS) and then read the file again  .
3. When columns 5 and 6 contain `-` only.

   - Append the look-up table to the pattern space (PS)
   - Do a look up using the first column as the key and if it fails delete that
     line.
   - For all remaining lines remove the look-up table.

Comment: LOL. Looks like you had a bad day with the keyboard. ;)